# Hive to avoid converting to Scientific

Tags: hive

I have a value conversion error as below in hive. How to solve it.

```
select 28200*100000;
select cast(28200*100000 as BIGINT);
output: -1474967296
```

Actual output should be

```
2820000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query Hive is automatically converting your result to integer because your are multiplying integers and the result exceed the Integer precision (it is pure Java at the end of the day). In your second query the cast is being done after the math operation, that is why you get the same result. You can perform this in the following ways

Casting before the math operation

```
select cast(28200 as bigint) * cast(100000 as bigint);
```

or indicating that the values are longs (so the result will be long as well)

```
select 28200L*100000L;
```

Comment: Got it!!.. so if int x int output is long it will not convert to long(Hence the scintific). But int x long will convert to the higher precision so it will output long. select cast(28200 as bigint) *100000  also worked. Thanks !!

Comment: this is not scientific notation, it is just overflowing the max integer value